# GAE python Memory profiler / memory use

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having strange patterns of memory consumption in GAE using Python. I'm monitoring the memory use in every request at the very beginning and at the very end using `google.appengine.api.runtime.memory_usage().current()`.  I have a request that at the begin and end uses 42MB and the next request, 3 minutes later, started with 117MB of memory usage, and ended with the same 117MB.
My question is what happened between the two only request of the only one instance used that caused a 75MB memory extra usage?

I'm looking for a memory profiler that let me go deep in an instance and see how is the memory being used, by what global variables, what processes, code, modules imported, and so on.

In this case the normal memory profiler tools doesn't help because the extra memory usage occurs outside a request, so I'm thinking in connect to the instance using the remote_api_shell and from them debug/profile the memory.

If anyone can help me or have experienced similar memory strange comsumptions and solutions I will appreciate.

Comment: I'd analyze which code is running and attempt to determine whether there are memory side-effects of anything that code is doing. In general, this question is bad for stackoverflow since you're asking for a tools recommendation. I'd use Google to find that if I were you.

Comment: Nick, I'm senior in this work... Obviously I checked all the code for side effects, and there is nothing wrong. Simply I'm asking if someone has experienced this issue. And the tool reccomedation is because previusly I checked and i did't found anything suitable for this in GAE, at this level,of detail. I have seroius problems with this and the garbage collection is not working well.

Comment: If your memory is growing in the way you describe, and you can't find any code which would have memory side effects, that doesn't sound right. I think it's a case of not having thoroughly-enough investigated possible memory side-effects. For example, are you using the `ndb` module for Datastore interaction? Are you aware it uses an in-memory cache to serve results and buffer writes? Are you storing session data in any way? There are many, many reasons why the memory on an instance would climb over time.

Comment: At any rate, tools recommendations are not proper for stackoverflow, and that's just the rules here.

Comment: There are plenty of resources out there which would advise you on how to memory-profile in python, if you would google for it. [Here](http://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis/)'s one such result.

Comment: There is a known memory leak in ndb, which Google has not addressed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35901184. I've taken every step listed in that issue report, and found that it does not eliminate my problem.